# Unable to get a File handle for a URI that starts with "content://0@media/"

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

In order to access a video and share it via our app, I am trying to access it using a FileProvider. The code works fine for all URIs except the one starting with "content://0@media/". In this specific case, the check "vidFile.exists()" returns false. Please let me know how to access files that have such content URI. Appreciate your help.

```
File vidFile = new File(uri.getPath());
if (vidFile.exists()) //This is returning false for this content URI
{
    Uri vidUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
            context,
            context.getString(R.string.file_provider_authority),
            vidFile);
}
```

Comment: It is not a file. You already have a `content` `Uri` for it, and so you do not need `FileProvider`.

Comment: Thank you, I used getContentResolver().query and I could get the video attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I used getContentResolver().query and I could get the video attributes. No need to use FileProvider as CommonsWare commented.